# Navigation Controller customisation not corresponding

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have customised/styled my `UINavigationController` in the `AppDelegate.swift` file. There are no errors in my code. Though, when I run my code in the built-in simulator, these changes aren't shown. How do I fix this? (I am using swift code.)

Here is my `AppDelegate.swift` code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Changing the navigation controller's background colour
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 165.0/255.0, blue: 227.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    // Changing the navigation controller's text/bar button item colour
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Changing the tint colour of the tab bar icons
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255/0, green: 165.0/255.0, blue: 227.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    // Changing the status bar's colour to white
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    return true
}
```

Here is an image of my simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor` not affecting color of title's font. Font's color can be changed via `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]`

To change color of status bar you also have to add `View controller-based status bar appearance` key to your `info.plist` and set its value to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you mean that the search icon on the left of navigation bar should be white instead of black right?

Have you checked the code in viewDidLoad: or the like that may unintentionally set this tintColor value into black? It may override your change here.

Comment: I haven't added any code for the UINavigationController in any viewDidLoad: methods. Only in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in the App Delegate, which is above.

Comment: Ok. Do you use storyboard to set up that view controller? Have you set the search icon as black colour there?

Comment: No, I have set it as white.